# SQL count player period points

Tags: sql

I have this table of game points, where every point is on the list with 4 columns: who has got it, in which game it was, in which period, and date of the game.

I can't get my head around how to calculate how many points each player got in each period of each game. I also want to put them in order of the game day and the period (first and second).

So far I have tried this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(POINTS) 
FROM 
    (SELECT POINTS, PERIOD 
     FROM POINTS_17 
     WHERE NAME = "player") 
WHERE 
    DISTINCT PERIOD ORDER BY DATE, PERIOD.
```

Any tips how to do this or where to start from? or is it possible at all?

Comment: not sure where you got "where distinct period" from but that isn't valid SQL syntax, so if you had tried it it would produce an error. SELECT **sum(POINTS)**,PERIOD FROM POINTS_17 WHERE NAME="player" **group by period**

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The use of double quotes for a string constant is invalid standard SQL.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Thanks @Used_By_Already! Yes, my version gives an error. I got it work with group by period: SELECT sum(POINTS),PERIOD FROM POINTS_17 WHERE NAME="player" group by PERIOD,GAME_NUMBER ORDER BY GAME_NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

1) Use single quotes, not double quotes.

2) Your question implies grouping, yet asks for ordering on columns that cannot be grouped.

3) I've included a few queries that might answer your question.

4) These first three queries show stats for a particular player. The last three queries show the same stats for every player.

```
-- Show a player's stats, ordered by date and period (like you asked). Since there is only one record per date/period, you don't need to SUM the values.
SELECT DATE, PERIOD, POINTS
FROM POINTS_17
WHERE NAME = 'player'
ORDER BY DATE, PERIOD;

-- Get the total and average points per period for a particular player (1st and 2nd period showed separately)
SELECT PERIOD, SUM(POINTS) AS TOTAL_POINTS, AVG(POINTS+0.0) AVERAGE_POINTS, COUNT(*) TOTAL_PERIODS
FROM POINTS_17
WHERE NAME = 'player'
GROUP BY PERIOD
ORDER BY PERIOD;

-- Get the total and average points per period for a particular player
SELECT SUM(POINTS) AS TOTAL_POINTS, AVG(POINTS+0.0) AVERAGE_POINTS, COUNT(*) TOTAL_PERIODS
FROM POINTS_17
WHERE NAME = 'player';




-- Show each player's stats, ordered by date and period.
SELECT NAME, DATE, PERIOD, POINTS
FROM POINTS_17
ORDER BY NAME, DATE, PERIOD;

-- Get the total and average points per period for every player (1st and 2nd period showed separately)
SELECT NAME, PERIOD, SUM(POINTS) AS TOTAL_POINTS, AVG(POINTS+0.0) AVERAGE_POINTS, COUNT(*) TOTAL_PERIODS
FROM POINTS_17
GROUP BY NAME, PERIOD
ORDER BY NAME, PERIOD;

-- Get the total and average points per period for every player
SELECT NAME, SUM(POINTS) AS TOTAL_POINTS, AVG(POINTS+0.0) AVERAGE_POINTS, COUNT(*) TOTAL_PERIODS
FROM POINTS_17
GROUP BY NAME;
```

Comment: I should note that this will only show stats for records in the table. Thus, if a player scored 0 points in a particular period, you must add a row if you want that to affect their average score per period (unless you want to modify the query a bit).